# What's the use of money?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So, I just finished the main storyline of Assassins Creed 3. In the beginning of the game, they showed me some crazy complicated method of trading supplies - I never bothered doing anything with it. I figured that if I need money later on I will get it done then. So when I finished I only had about £7,000

But... I never needed any money. I played the whole game only spending a few dollars bribing heralds every now and again.

I didn't have to purchase any weapons (the tomahawk was good enough for the whole game), I never had to upgrade any armour (was there upgraded armour even for sale?).

Did I miss something important? Or was this game much simpler than its predecessors (in terms of needing money, anyway)?

Comment: I was just like you, I didn't really do much with my money. The trading system just felt like a waste of time. About the only thing I did do was craft upgrades and that's it.

Comment: Main reason to gather money, is to upgrade the Achilles and buy new maps (for completion purpose). Ammo is replenished much faster and more comfortably by looting dead guards, and looting chests is much faster and less annoying than sending convoys and having to run to their rescue every now and then. Money has always been pretty pointless in AC, tbh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a very similar experience as you.

The main thing I spent my money on was upgrades for the Aquila.

The towns carried new weapons you could buy, but nothing that was substantially better than what is given to you for free.

Other than that, the only thing to really spend money on was treasure maps & decorations for your house (made through crafting).

Comment: Yep, I was going to mention ship upgrades. Considering some of these can be £14,000+ it seems the only use for the trading element of the game. Something to grind for completionists.

Comment: I think you mean the Aquila, and not Achilles?

Comment: @LOL.NO. Thank you. I have edited my answer. Achilles is actually your mentor.

Answer (score 0):

You can spend your money at the general store, which is marked on your map as £. There you can buy lots of stuff such as: weapons, clothing, maps, arrows, and many more! Hope this helped:)

Answer (score -1):

Ship upgrades, that's what I spent my money on after I finished the game.